# Labeling mulitple interests stacking problem

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, labeling, maplex

I am using ArcView 10.1 and am using this code to no avail in the Labeling Properties  [Company_Ne] &VBNEWLINE& [Exp_Date_O]

I know there is a way but am not familiar with the scripting for it.  I am trying to label each parcel but there are multiple tracts that have different expiration and company net acres.

One tract may have only one Lessee,just one exp date and company net acre.

another tract have multiple (ranges 2-9+) shared interests, so they will have different exp dates and different company net acres.  Is there a way to include all those in there without them stacking up on top of each other, but layered underneath one another?

There are 2 columns I am using for the labeling.  I am trying to make them look like the top Left (centered left side). 
[image]

Comment: Could you add how you want your label to look? And from which fields they will get their data?

Comment: I made the edit.  I can manually go in via mineral annotations and do the adustments but there are way too many to do it that way.